# How long has passed in Fort Salem?

Tags: time, motherland-fort-salem

[*Motherland: Fort Salem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherland:_Fort_Salem) follows Raelle Collar, Abigail Bellweather and Tally Craven, three witches who are enlisted in the U.S. Army. By the end of the first season, they have completed basic and are moving onto the next phase. But it's not clear to me how much time has passed, weeks, months, years?

Not much time seems to go by in early episodes as the cadets prepared for Beltane, but a lot seems to happen off camera as the series progresses, the cadets 'work' skills for one.

Comment: 10-16 weeks depending on their speciality; https://www.benning.army.mil/Common/Faqs/BCT-FAQ.html

Comment: Te accords were signed on the 19th of February 1692, conscription day occurs every year on that date, and the girls catch flights the next day meaning the first day at Fort Salem is the 20th of February. 

Beltane occurs on May 1st, meaning 10 weeks since the girls arrived on base. The Bellweather wedding takes place 1 week later, so 11 weeks as of Episode 5. Not sure how many weeks are between ep 5 and 10 tho